# C# How to Serialize XML from text/checbox on a loop based on button click

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, checkbox, textbox

I am trying to serialize values in a user control based on a button click: [C# WinForm Validate Checkbox and Error if at least one is unselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963364/c-sharp-winform-validate-checkbox-and-error-if-at-least-one-is-unselected/33963455#33963455)

The serialzation is not unlike [this](https://blog.udemy.com/csharp-serialize-to-xml/)

I have 1 problem and few questions.

The problem is, I cannot call this from within my foreach process on button click (it is outwith of this).

The questions:

I am defining a string for each checkbox upon check; the name in the string should be related to the public string used for the XML section, is this a sensible approach? e.g.

```
public static string CheckBoxString;
        private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                CheckBoxString = "SESSIONNAMEValue";
            }
        }
```

Next question:

If I have multiple user controls all writing to the same XML at various stages e.g. user control 1 writes the sessionname for each checkbox, two writes name for each checkbox, three writes time for each checkbox.

How should I best manage this? I didn't think update the file was the best approach but I didnt want to write everything back to the form to store and process at the end...

Example XML:

```
<CONFIG1>
   <SESSIONNAME>SOMETHINGHERE</SESSIONNAME>
   <NAME>NAMEHERE</NAME>
   <DATETIME>DATE</DATETIME>
</CONFIG1>

<CONFIG2>
   <SESSIONNAME>SOMETHINGHERE</SESSIONNAME>
   <NAME>NAMEHERE</NAME>
   <DATETIME>DATE</DATETIME>
</CONFIG2>
```

**UPDATED WITH SOURCE**

The source is now working and I can table my checkbox string and write it to the XML file, but if I have two checkboxes selected, the first is overwritten and not the last is appended to the file.

```
public class Config
            {
            public string SESSIONNAME { get; set; }
            public string NAME { get; set; }
            public int DATETIME { get; set; }


        }

        public class XMLSer
        {
            public List<Config> GetConfigList()
            {

                List<Config> configs = new List<Config>();
                configs.Add(new Config { SESSIONNAME = CheckBoxString, NAME = “TEST NAME”});            
                return configs;
            }
        }


        public static string CheckBoxString;
        private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                ProductCheckBoxString = “CheckBox1”;
                MessageBox.Show(CheckBoxString);
            }


        }

        private void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (CheckBox2.Checked)
            {
                ProductCheckBoxString = “CheckBox2”;
                MessageBox.Show(CheckBoxString);
            }


        }

        private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

            private void ValidateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Boolean checkboxFlag = false;
            foreach (var control in this.Controls)
            {
                if (control is CheckBox)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)control).Checked)
                    {
                        foreach (var checkBox in this.Controls)
                        {
                            XMLSer xmlser = new XMLSer();
                            var cfglist = xmlser.GetConfigList();

                            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Config>));
                            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"testout.xml"))
                            {
                                serializer.Serialize(writer, cfglist);
                            }
                        }
                        checkboxFlag = true;
                        ValidateButton.Hide();
                        NextButton.Show();

                    }
                }

            }
```

**Working XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Config>
    <SESSIONNAME>CheckBox1</SESSIONNAME>
    <NAME>TEST NAME</NAME>
  </Config>
</ArrayOfConfig>
```

So, now I have only two problems:

I would like to write each set of values to their own config section on after another to the same file, I prefer this format after seeing the above output.

```
<SESSIONNAME0>
   <NAME>NAMEHERE</NAME>
   <DATETIME>DATE</DATETIME>
</SESSIONNAME0>

<SESSIONNAME1>
   <NAME>NAMEHERE</NAME>
   <DATETIME>DATE</DATETIME>
</SESSIONNAME1>
```

How do I add the config class to a sperate class file, so I can share it with all other user controls, and not have to have to manage the same code everywhere

Comment: Can you please send the rest of the code?

Comment: Added update. Also it is now working, just need help with the final part :)